# AngularJS ng-required not working with variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to use the directive ng-required, but I cannot hardcode true or false. I need to use it in a variable, but angular does not recognize the "true".

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v2gTp/1/)

```
<div ng-app ng-init="test=true">
    <div>
        both have ng-required="true"
        <br/>
        one as hardcoded string literal, one via a variable
        <br/>
        Inspect them, one is not required!
    </div>
    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" ng-required="{{test}}" />
        <input type="text" ng-required="true" />
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-required="{{test}}" />
```

You don't need to interpolate *test* here. Since you want to evaluate the value of test, just remove the curly braces and it should work.

Comment: I see. The ng-required directive tries to directly access a variable in the scope named by the given string literal. Once It evaluates {{test}} to "true" it tries to find scope.true and this is undefined. Undefined is not == true, so it is not required. Thanks for that!

Comment: The result of an interpolation is always a string.

Comment: @JM. you are the guy!

Answer (score 5):

Just discovered yesterday you can use ng-required in the same pattern as ng-class:

```
<input type = "text" ng-required = "{true : 'true', false : 'false'}[test]" />
```

Comment: I did tried  ng-required = "{true : 'true', false : 'false'}[test]" as your suggested but I curious why ng-required="{{test}}" does not work?

Comment: @Yoo in the Angular Directives, you don't have to wrap your expressions with the double brackets '{{}}' because it's already done. You have to it on non-Angular parameters however, like 'name', 'class', 'id' ...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use ternary operators into these kind of directives, and it works well. For the ng-required :

```
<input type="text" ng-required="(user.name == '' ? 'true' : 'false')" ng-model="user.nickname"/>
```

In this example, if the name field of the user is not filled, the nickname field become REQUIRED.

Comment: Could you explain why `ng-required="user.name == ''"` is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, both answers does not work, just use

```
ng-required="expired"
```

with expired to be a variable.

Comment: The accepted says exactly the same. Please read it more carefully.